# Show expanded float value in Android

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a function that simply converts units, and my goal is for the output number to be displayed in expanded form, as in showing the full number, not "3.0E7". The code is as follows:

```
public void convertUnits(View view)
{
    EditText fromNumberEditText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.fromField);
    TextView toNumberEditText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.toField);
    String fromUnitString = selectedList[selectedLeftItem];
    String toUnitString = selectedList[selectedRightItem];

    float fromUnit = Float.parseFloat(fromUnitString.split(",")[2]);
    float toUnit = Float.parseFloat(toUnitString.split(",")[2]);
    float fromNumber = Float.parseFloat(fromNumberEditText.getText().toString());
    float toNumber = (fromNumber * fromUnit) / toUnit;
    toNumberEditText.setText(Float.toString(toNumber));
}
```

The toNumberEditText has marquee, and because of that I would like for it to show the expanded number, i.e. 30000000 not 3.0E7. Whenever the toNumber float is anything more than 7 digits it assumes the "floating e" form. Is there a way to either change the amount of digits before it does this, or remove it altogether?

Comment: Might be better to use `String.format()` instead of `Float.toString()`. That or `DecimalFormat`.

Answer (score 1):

Use String.format():

```
toNumberEditText.setText(String.format("%f", toNumber));
```